# jQuery - auto suggest/complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for a good solution for an autocomplete/autosuggest jQuery plugin. The ones I have found stops auto-completing/suggesting after a value is selected. I'm trying to mimic Google Suggest.

For example, say I provide the following options:

- aaa
- bbb
- ccc

When user type in `a`, the user should be presented with `aaa`. If user selects that, then presses a space (meaning, user is getting ready to type some more), I want `bbb` and `ccc` still available to the user when he/she is typing.

Any suggestions for what I might be able to use?

(NOTE: Perhaps Google Suggest actually behaves the same way as the available plugins. Perhaps its list of options just contain every possible permutation of what the user might type.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I think your right about google having every possible permutation.

I would suggest keeping with the standard jquery autocomplete plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).

Comment: I just noticed that SO behaves the same. You think SO has every possible permutation, too? Seems inefficient.

Comment: Are you referring to the "tags editor" (I can't seem to get autocomplete to work within the search at the top of the page)? The tags editor is using jQuery's autocomplete. The code for it is within http://sstatic.net/Js/tageditor.js. One of the options, multiple, seems to be controlling the ability to search on the current word being typed (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:
nicolasbize.github.com/magicsuggest

You will get the desired behaviour with the following code:

```
new MagicSuggest({
    focusOnExpand: true,
    data: 'aaa,bbb,ccc',
    renderTo: $('#your-div-id')
})
```

disclaimer: i am the author

Comment: You seem to have gone on a bit of a rampage of advertising your own stuff here, lately.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. :( i tried being specific each time but even then all the posts ended up being deleted by mods. This answer is the only reference  that i'll post about it. I guess i was afraid noone would look at it.